# Magento admin URL failure

Tags: admin, magento2.2, url

I successfully changed my store domain name and I was able to access my admin URL. Now when I changed my admin URL and getting 404 error. I followed these steps:

STORES → Configuration-Admin-ADVANCED-Admin Base URL-use custom url-yes
and then entered my custom admin URL.
Custom admin path is set to no while saving configuration.

On saving, the page went immediately to 404 error. Now I'm unable to access my admin URL.

Even after cache clear and flush, I'm still unable to access admin URL.
I tried to edit env.php but still no luck.

Any other steps to get back to the admin url. Should I try editing db from phpmyadmin?

Magento ver: 2.2

Comment: you can delete custom url entry from phpmyadmin to get back the previous url

Comment: I deleted custom url entry but still getting 404 error.

Comment: please clear the cache and check

Comment: you can also run the command php bin/magento info:adminuri to get admin url

Comment: I have cleared the cache and the info:adminuri returns the url. But still getting 404

Comment: Now after various changes, Im able to get admin url. But its opening without the JS and CSS.

Comment: just need to run all the command again